# Validation loss is less than training loss by 5 units. How this result is interpreted?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, speech-to-text

Iam training a Keras model for end-to-end speech recognition. I have my own dataset of speech containing about 400 wave files. Text transcriptions is also given as input. Model summary is:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
the_input (InputLayer)       (None, None, 26)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
layer_1_conv (Conv1D)        (None, None, 30)          3930      
_________________________________________________________________
conv_batch_norm (BatchNormal (None, None, 30)          120       
_________________________________________________________________
rnn_bi (GRU)                 (None, None, 40)          8520      
_________________________________________________________________
bt_rnn_bi (BatchNormalizatio (None, None, 40)          160       
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_15 (Bidirectio (None, None, 40)          19440     
_________________________________________________________________
bt_rnn_final (BatchNormaliza (None, None, 40)          160       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_15 (TimeDis (None, None, 29)          1189      
_________________________________________________________________
softmax (Activation)         (None, None, 29)          0         
=================================================================
Total params: 33,519
Trainable params: 33,299
Non-trainable params: 220
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

- Optimiser used: `Adadelta()`
- Loss function: `ctc_loss` function.
- Dropout: 0.5

Training and validation loss in last epochs is:

```
Epoch 392/400
27/27 [==============================] - 36s - loss: 19.9499 - val_loss: 16.5945

Epoch 393/400
27/27 [==============================] - 34s - loss: 18.9789 - val_loss: 14.1015

Epoch 394/400
27/27 [==============================] - 36s - loss: 17.9598 - val_loss: 14.2997

Epoch 395/400
27/27 [==============================] - 34s - loss: 17.1506 - val_loss: 15.1215

Epoch 396/400
27/27 [==============================] - 35s - loss: 17.4900 - val_loss: 14.0334

Epoch 397/400
27/27 [==============================] - 35s - loss: 17.7459 - val_loss: 14.7812

Epoch 398/400
27/27 [==============================] - 35s - loss: 18.3460 -  val_loss: 14.4461

Epoch 399/400
27/27 [==============================] - 35s - loss: 17.4311 - val_loss: 15.5965

Epoch 400/400
27/27 [==============================] - 35s - loss: 17.6892 - val_loss: 12.4165
```

Can anybody explain to me how this loss is interpreted? What could be the correct values of training loss and validation loss, so my model correctly predicts the output values?

I tried reducing the loss and it did reduce, with the difference of plus or minus 1 unit, but test tests were totally incorrect. Can anyone suggest me ways to gain correct test results?

Answer (score 1):

The key here is dropout. When a model trains with dropout, only a percentage of the total weights (in your case 50%) are used in predictions, which tends to lower the prediction accuracy. When the validation data is tested, dropout is turned off, and the validation loss tends to be a lot lower. see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187335/validation-error-less-than-training-error/187404#187404) to a similar question for more info.